# How can I customize permission request view in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, core-location, ios-permissions

I know that it's not possible to customize for instance location permission view in iOS, but I'm wondering how AirBnb application do it?
It have custom view for both location and notification permissions. I read that AirBnb mobile application is ReactNative, you can find info [here](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/react-native-at-airbnb-f95aa460be1c), maybe that's why they can customize permissions view? 
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't customize the default iOS permission alert. Those are triggered by the system when you ask for the permission (like camera or location).

What Airbnb and others do, is show a custom view **before** the native one i.e before asking for the permission.

Comment: Ok AirBnb asks befog, but it never shows native permissions alert views, that's the question, how they get access.

Comment: If you ask for a permission iOS will show the alert. That's not something you can control to show or not.